# break statement inside if statement which is comprised in nested for loop?

Tags: javascript

```
var num=0;
outermost: for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  for(var j=0;j<10;j++)
  {
     if(i==5 && j==5)
      {
        break outermost;
      }
   num++;
  }
}
console.log(num); //Answers 55
```

How this stuff work I mean once value of J transits from 0 to 1 it enters into loop of J,then j loop will run 10 times(i think),then how come this loop will break? 
i m new to programming kindly Yelp!

Comment: you can read it as: `break outermost;` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement is executed when the `if` statement is entered.

The `if` statement is entered when `i==5 && j==5` evaluates to `true`.

That happens when `i` is equal to 5 AND `j` is equal to 5.

For `i` to get to 5, the outer loop has to run a full 5 times (for i = 0,1,2,4). This means that the inner loop runs 5*10 = 50 times. For `j` to get to 5 on the last run of the inner loop, the inner loop must run 5 times (for j = 0,1,2,3,4). In total, the inner loop must run 55 times, which means that the `num` variable will hold 55.

Comment: NO my question is when i enters the loop the value is incremented by one then we enter into the second loop which runs  10 times then,again the outer loop increments to two then how come the value of i and j will be five at the same instance..

Comment: The value of `j` is set to 0 every time the inner loop is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Put `console.log(i + " " + j + " " + num);` inside the inner loop, before `if`.

It will show everything you have to know.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the outermost loop iterates it increases `i` by one and `num` by ten(because it is inside the inner loop, which iterates ten times every outermost loop iteration, so `num` is increased ten times). When you reach the sixth iteration `i` is 5 and `j` is 0. The inner loop  iterates 5 times, which causes `j` to become 5. Up to now `num` has become 55. In the next iteration the if control succeeds, in fact `i == 5 && j == 5`, breaking the outermost loop, and leaving `num` to be 55. Since the `num++` statement is placed **after** the if condition this 56th iteration won't be complete, and won't increase `num` to 56. But the iterations are about 55 + 1/2.

Why does `j` reset itself after every outermost iteration? Because it is scoped inside the loop, so after every outermost iteration it is destroyed and created again.